# Best way to populate a page with dynamic content

Tags: php, jquery

I have been thinking about this for some time now, for the purpose of an example lets say we have index.php which has a whole bunch of content and a search box, when a user inputs data into the search box results appear below such as images and data for each result.

What is the best way to populate these results?

**Example one**

> AJAX Post to results.php which echos the complete results including
>       HTML and aesthetic tags. Then back on the first page include 
>       all the data that was returned using .html(data);

**Example Two**

> Have the skeleton of the results and hide them, (wrapper 
>       divs and everything that is included for each result) 
>       And then AJAX and retrieve data and populate the divs and show them

Or any other suggestions you may have?

Answer (score 1):

1. User enters in search term.
2. Perform AJAX GET to results.php.
3. Return data from results.php in JSON format.
4. Replace search results with said data.

Answer (score 1):

this is in the index.php

```
$('#search').live('click',function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'result.php',
    data: {keyword: $('#search_box').val()},
    type: 'POST',
    dataTupe: 'json',
    success: function(response){
      $('.result_box').html(response['data']);      
    }
  });
});
```

this is how your result.php swill look like

```
$keyword = $_POST['keyword'];    
$result = getResults($keyword);    
die(json_encode(array('data'=>$result)));
```

getResults function should be where you retrieve the data based on your keyword search.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the structure doesn't change, it is better to use JSON and populate in the local JavaScript.

Consider there are set of books. Around 100. And if you gonna output the HTML to be updated, it would surely cost much. While, you output just the thing like:

```
{
    success:true,
    rows:[{
        "id":"1",
        "title":"Office Space",
        "director":"Mike Judge",
        "released":"1999-02-19",
        "genre":"1",
        "tagline":"Work Sucks",
        "coverthumb":"84m.jpg",
        "price":"19.95",
        "available":"1"
    },{
        "id":"3",
        "title":"Super Troopers",
        "director":"Jay Chandrasekhar",
        "released":"2002-02-15",
        "genre":"1",
        "tagline":"Altered State Police",
        "coverthumb":"42m.jpg",
        "price":"14.95",
        "available":"1"
    },{
        "id":"4",
        "title":"American Beauty",
        "director":"Sam Mendes",
        "released":"1999-10-01",
        "genre":"2",
        "tagline":"... Look Closer",
        "coverthumb":"12m.jpg",
        "price":"19.95",
        "available":"1"
    },{
        "id":"5",
        "title":"The Big Lebowski",
        "director":"Joel Coen",
        "released":"1998-03-06",
        "genre":"1",
        "tagline":"The \"Dude\"",
        "coverthumb":"49m.jpg",
        "price":"21.90",
        "available":"1"
    },{
        "id":"6",
        "title":"Fight Club",
        "director":"David Fincher",
        "released":"1999-10-15",
        "genre":"3",
        "tagline":"How much can you know about yourself...",
        "coverthumb":"94m.jpg",
        "price":"19.95",
        "available":"1"
    }]
}
```

This can be very well parsed by jQuery.parseJSON and displayed as `table` or inside `li`s or complex `div`s.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what's easier for you in terms of current page structure and the structure of received data. Both approaches are completely fine, although I might be leaning a bit towards the first one since it's easier to use and you can format the output in the PHP file (in case you need that)... yet the only difference is basically the amount of data received by AJAX and with today's internet speeds, a couple of HTML tags along with the content won't make much of a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The second option is much better IMHO, use JSON to grab the data, and worry about inserting it on the client side, after you retrive it. Think about it this way: the less data you're sending / receiving the better. 
Here's couple of points

- The code is **easier to maintain**, if you're just passing JSON, and your views have to change at a later date.
- Code is **more readable** for devs if they're just passing JSON, they can fix issues with the data easier without having to go through lots of layout HTML structure.

Comment: But if I have the skeletons of say 20 results on the page but hidden, if there are only 6 results returned i will have a bunch of empty skeletons being shown?

Comment: I assume your skeletons will be the same for each data, so you should really have only one, and then duplicate for however many results you get from AJAX

Comment: So i have the skeleton in the jquery? Or hidden on the page?

Comment: you can do either. have the skeleton on the page, which in my opinion would be more appropriate and then .clone() it, or you could create DOM elements. But I would go with a hidden skeleton in HTML

Answer (score 0):

Both is possibel but going with the full html answer (option 1) is better in most cases.
If you have a dynamic php page you shoulld use a template engine.

I usually end up with multiple templates: A main template with the page structure, a menu template, a article template ... and in your case the result template.

Then you can make your search request with or without ajax. If js is enabled you just render the results with the "result" template; return the html fragment and insert it into the apropiate point of your page.

If js is diasbled, you request a new page which renders the results in a new Page.

You COULD use a js template engine too, but so far I have found none which has a decent implementation in PHP and js.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is the best option as it sends a lot less data. An example straight from Jquery docs showing that you don't need to generate a skeleton for your data. As you can see the only thing you need to create is a container to hold the elements created from the javascript. `<img>` tags are created as needed and appended in to the specified `images` div container.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>img{ height: 100px; float: left; }</style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="images">

</div>
<script>
    $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
        {
            tags: "mount rainier",
            tagmode: "any",
            format: "json"
        },
        function(data) {
            $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
                $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
                if ( i == 3 ) return false;
            });
        });</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I spend a lot of time on designing and each result has multiple tags, it would not be just a image tag, would this be a issue?

Comment: Of course not this is a very basic example. There are many examples on stackoverflow which would match almost to exactly what you need.